# какие типы присвоить ?

Tags: json, swift

Есть вот такой json , какие типы мне присвоить в struct чтобы у меня не было ошибки

```
 {
  "status": "success",
  "value": {
    "info": [
      {
        "title": "Нажать на кнопку \"Перейти на сайт\" QIWI RUB и сделать перевод по реквизитам",
        "value": "+79587842193", //вот здесь должен быть тип string
        "extra": "RUR"
      },

      {
        "title": "Сумма зачисления",
        "value": 99,  //вот здесь должен быть тип int
        "extra": "USD"
      }
    ],
    "alert": ""
  }
}
```

вот мой struct

```
struct ResponsePaiinfo: Codable {
    let status: String
    let value: Valuepayinfo
}
struct Valuepayinfo: Codable {
    let info: Info
    let alert: String
}
struct Info: Codable {
    let title: String 
    let value: String //какой здесь указать тип ?
    let extra: String
}
```

Comment: Почему не получается использовать Int?

Answer (score 1):

Если в json есть кавычки вокруг числа - это Int. В противном случае - String

Comment: А не наоборот ?

Comment: Да, мой косяк)) в точности наоборот

Answer (score 1):

можно так, но сработает только если там только два типа для `value`

```
struct Info: Codable {

    let title: String
    let value: String
    let extra: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case value = "value"
        case title = "title"
        case extra = "extra"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        extra = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .extra)
        do {

            value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .value)

        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {

            let intValue = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .value)
            value = "\(intValue)"
        }
    }
}
```

или так

```
struct Info: Codable {

    let title: String
    let value: String
    let extra: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case value = "value"
        case title = "title"
        case extra = "extra"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.extra = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .extra)
        if let stringValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .value) {
            value = Info.stringify(stringValue)
        } else {
            let intValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .value)
            value = Info.stringify(intValue)
        }
    }

    private static func stringify<Value>(_ value: Value) -> String {
        return "\(value)"
    }
}
```